# How to get fixed margin between body and footer

Tags: html, css, footer

I am new to CSS and am trying to set up a page so that there is always a **fixed margin / space between the page's main content (sidebar / sections) and the footer** (e.g. 120px) which should work cross-browser.
Also, in case there is very little content on a page the **footer should always appear at least at the bottom** of the (visible) screen.

I made multiple attempts by applying a class `footer`, including the following, but the margin is always ignored.

```css
.footer {
    color: #333;
    font-size: 11px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: bottom
}
.footer:before {
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    height: 120px;
    min-height: 120px;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <!-- ... -->
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav>
            <!-- ... -->
        </nav>
        <section id="sidebar">
            <!-- ... -->
        </section>
        <section id="main">
            <!-- ... -->
        </section>
        <footer class="footer">
            <div>Some text</div>
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

Can someone help me with this?
Also, if anything should be changed regarding my HTML please let me know as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should help:

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    margin:0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
.wrap {
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto -80px; /* footer height + space */
    min-height: 100%;
    padding: 0 0 80px; /* footer height + space */
    box-sizing: border-box;
    overflow: auto;
}
.footer {
    background-color: #111111;
    color: #eeeeee;
    border-top: 1px solid red;
    height: 60px;  /* footer height */
    padding-top: 20px;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 20px; /* space between content and footer */
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="wrap">
        <nav>
            <!-- ... -->
        </nav>
        <section id="sidebar">
            <!-- ... -->
        </section>
        <section id="main">
            <!-- ... -->
            
        </section>
    </div>
    <footer class="footer">
        <div>Some text</div>
    </footer>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! This did the trick and it works great ! I was playing around with the wrapper before but think my mistake was that I had it wrapped around the wrong elements. :)

Comment: Update: I came across some issues here when testing this with more content and on smaller screens but found a way to fix this as well: In my case adding "width: 100%;" and "position: relative;" to the footer and, most importantly, "overflow: auto;" to the wrapper resolved that.

Comment: This answer would be improved drastically by making an effort to explain why it "should help".

Answer (score 2):

Why you use ":before"?

Your css should look like this:

```
.footer {
    color: #333;
    font-size: 11px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    margin-top: 120px;
}
```

Try this example (works fine for me).
If it not works - make sure you use css reset.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8" />
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
            <!-- ... -->
        </head>
        <body>
            <nav style="background:grey;height:100px;">
                <!-- ... -->
            </nav>
            <section id="sidebar" style="background:green;height:100px;">
                <!-- ... -->
            </section>
            <section id="main" style="background:red;height:100px;">
                <!-- ... -->
            </section>
            <footer class="footer" style="background:blue;">
                <div>Some text</div>
            </footer>
        </body>
    </html>

<style>
.footer {
    color: #333;
    font-size: 11px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    margin-top: 120px;
}

</style>
```

Comment: Thanks ! This doesn't change it for me. I  had tried the margin-top earlier as well. I had added the :before style for the clear style to prevent any floating.

Comment: Thanks ! I tried this and it shows the footer at the bottom but it doesn't show the margin between it and the content above. Can you explain what you mean with CSS reset ?

Answer (score 2):

To add a margin between the body and footer, just add this to the style of the footer section:
`padding:20px 0px 0px 0px;`

Keeping the footer at the bottom is more complicated.  Try something like this for css:

```
html, body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:100%;
}

#wrapper{              /*create a div around whole html body
    min-height:100%;
    position:relative;
}

#main{
    padding-bottom:100px; /* Height of the footer element */
}

#footer {
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    color: #333;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! This goes in the right direction but it moves the footer to the middle of the page where it is overlapping the rest of my content. Also, I don't have something called main at the moment but I tried giving a section that id - could that be it ?

Comment: In your HTML: `<section id="main">` ?

Comment: Yes, that's what I tried. I can live without the sticky footer but need a way to fix the margin.

Comment: Try messing with this: [link](http://www.cssreset.com/demos/layouts/how-to-keep-footer-at-bottom-of-page-with-css/)

Answer (score 0):

just give styling to body with margin 0px.

```
  body{
      margin: 0px;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't change anything. What I am looking for is to set a fixed margin between the main content and the footer.

Comment: than you can give margin to all 3 tags.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm a little late to the party, but you could also just guesstimate with some set units for `vh`. Hacky, but it works in a pinch.

```
.wrap {
    min-height: 70vh;
}
```

```
<div class="wrap">
    <section id="chapterone">
        <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
    ...
</div>

<footer class="footer">
    <a href="/">Home</a>
    ...
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solved!**

In my case, I added id to the previous div (like "body") to the div above the footer div, as follows:

```
<div id="body" class="container">
   ...
</div>

<div class="row footer-row-bg">
       ...     
</div>
```

Then, in my CSS file, I added  `padding-bottom:20px;` for that id as follows:

```
#body{
    padding-bottom:20px;
}
```